Hardwood Floor Restoration
Hardwood Refinishing Project
I am refinishing my hardwood floors in a future rental property (I am the owner), this will be my first time doing this. I have sanded in stages up to 100 grit, edge sanded and still working on getting some scratches and other deep cuts out without creating divots.
Few questions:

What is the best nail filler that is sandable and matches the natural wood look. I filled it with some filler that ended up turning a really light, almost white color, so I'll probably drill the filled material out.

I was wondering if anyone was able to identify the strain of wood from the attached photos. I know the finishing process might depend on the type of wood. If it's not possible to identify by the photos, how would I go about identifying the type of wood?

Once all my prep work is done, I will be staining the floors. Once they are stained, do I need to seal it prior to adding a top coat? Product recommendations would be appreciated, from research, I will be staying away from Minwax brand or anything from the box stores really.



I think the best/closest matching wood filler you can get is stuff you mix up from the sanding dust.  Just not sure what glue you use, but think just wood glue.

That looks like vertical grain douglas fir to me.  It's a softwood, but it's really nice stuff.  Take good care of that floor!

@crip659, I initially tried the sanding dust and wood glue and it turned out even worse than the wood filler. I thought glue + wood dust would match perfectly, but I was mistaken on that. Thanks for the info

Test your stain on your filler - you may find that it appears lighter when unstained, but takes the stain differently to the point that it ends up darker - or well-matched. Identifying Wood by R. Bruce Hoadley is the book you'll want to get via your library (or buy, depending) for how to figure out what wood you have.
